Is it possible to use a Power BI API to update visual components (e.g. size) in PowerBI desktop report
I am very new to the PowerBI report, and recently, I have been given a task to update visual components (e.g., size, and colours) in the existing desktop reports according to their guidelines.
Instead of going over each report and updating it, I would like to create an app that can do this for me using a powerBI API.
I have been searching for it but haven't found anything like that for the desktop reports. Could you please help me with this?

There is no official API to edit pbix files directly, you might be able to manipulate the files programmatically.
Why ? because simply pbix files are essentially ZIP archives containing various files in JSON and XML formats.
While the REST API doesn't support direct modification of pbix files, you can use it to manage datasets, reports, and dashboards in the Power BI Service.
Try to create custom themes in JSON format and apply them to your reports if you want to standardize colors, fonts, and other visual elements but keep in mind you can only apply it to each report manually.
